# Executing OpenLDAP searches in VBS

Tags: windows, vbscript, ldap

I am trying to port over Thunderbird/Firefox profile customization scripts from OS X to Windows 7. On OS X they are super simple, using `ldapsearch -x -h ldap.place.edu uid="username"` to retrieve the email address, real name etc from the OpenLDAP server then throwing these variables into the various configuration files before the applications are loaded.

On Windows this is much more complex, I started trying to use the search.vbs activedirectory/ldap tool that comes with Windows Server 2003 but it doesn't work properly, I also tried simply writing a quick vbs script to connect and query but I always get errors either that the server won't process the request or that just fails... here is my latest vbs script that totally flunks out...

```
Dim oConn,oRS,vSearch,vCount,vMailList,vValue,vProblem,vMsg

vProblem = False

vSearch = "(uid=username)"

Set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oConn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
oConn.Open "ADs Provider", "ou=people,dc=place,dc=edu"

Set oRS = oConn.Execute("<LDAP://ldap.place.edu/dc=edu/dc=place>;" & vSearch &_";cn,mail")

vCount = 1
While not oRS.EOF

   For Each vValue in oRS.Fields(0).value
      WScript.Echo vValue
   Next

vCount = vCount + 1
oRS.MoveNext
Wend
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out a little while back and totally forgot about this, so here it is. I realised I was trying to connect to a anonymous server but was providing a DN while implies a password level of authentication instead of the simple version I needed.

```
'Server name
sRoot = "LDAP://server"    
Dim oDS: Set oDS = GetObject("LDAP:")
'Don't provide a DN for anonymous authentication, also &H0010 implies simple auth mode
Dim oAuth: Set oAuth = oDS.OpenDSObject(sRoot, "", "", &H0010)
Dim oConn: Set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oConn.Provider = "ADSDSOObject"
oConn.Open "Ads Provider", sDN
Dim rs
'Execute query
Set rs = oConn.Execute("<" & sRoot & ">;(uid=testuser);cn,mail;subtree")
'retrieve values
z = rs.Fields.Item(0).Value
x = rs.Fields.Item(1).Value
```